# Error while building the XCframework from Android KMM module

Tags: ios, kotlin-multiplatform, xcframework

I have an Android project within which I have created the new KMM module. It is perfectly working with the Android app module.
Now I want to generate the XCFramework out of that KMM module.

I am trying this gradle command to generate the XCFramework,

```
gradlew assembleXCFramework
```

Also tried,

```
gradlew assembleMySharedXCFramework
```

But both of these didn't work. Android Studio is giving me this error,

[image]

Comment: You'd need to post your config to get any sense of what's going on. Also, Kotlin 1.5.30 is *very* old for KMP. Current production is 1.9.21 (I believe).

Comment: Thank you, That was the issue. I fixed it by upgrading the Kotlin version.